# Stamping Template Async? Race condition issue

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.7

Is stamping a template a async operation? It's not I/O so I don't know why it would be. However, there is a race condition here where `this.$$('#uploadedImage1')` is undefined. It works if I use `<div hidden="[[foo]]">` instead of `template is="dom-if"`, so this is how I know it is a race condition.

```
  <template is="dom-if" if="[[uploadedImage1]]">
    <div id="uploadedImage1" class="row-image horizontal layout">
    </div>
  </template>
  ...
  ready: function(e) {
    function readURL(e) {
      var el = e.target.id
      var uploadedID = e.target.dataset.uploaded;
      var file = Polymer.dom(e).localTarget.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = ()=> {
        this[uploadedID] = true;
        //RACE CONDITION HERE
        this.$$('#uploadedImage1').style.backgroundImage = `url(${reader.result})`;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    this.$['images-container'].addEventListener('change', readURL.bind(this), false)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes, template stamping is async. Here, you could use an attribute binding to `style` to apply the background image directly, so you don't need to manipulate the stamped DOM.

If you really need to get at the stamped DOM, you can either a) wait for a `dom-change` event, or b) force a synchronous render by calling `render`. (The latter is usually an anti-pattern--you don't want to force something to happen synchronously if you don't have to.)

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#synchronous-renders
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-change

Note the docs as written may imply that only `dom-repeat` is rendered async, but `render` and `dom-change` are available on both elements.

Hope that helps.